# Statistics on a highly volative table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

We have a queue table that as the nature of that type of table are highly volatile. For the rest of the database do need to have automatic update of statistics turned on. This means that the statistics for the clustered index is continuously being updated. We do not have any non-clustered indexes on this table. When the traffic on the table is growing enough the statistics update is starting to block the inserts that are blocking the updates to the end that the queue is slowing down almost to a standstill.

I did turn on automatic update stats async and then solved the most critical blocking issues. Not ideal as it still is doing the updates. Any ideas of how to solve this continuous statistics update on this type of highly volatile tables?

Comment: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/06/25/sql-server-disable-statistics-update-on-a-specific-table/

Comment: How is the statistics update blocking inserts? As far as I have seen `StatMan` queries run with a `READUNCOMMITTED` hint

Comment: Sure, it is not by itself locking the table but when not using asynch then the query triggering the stats update will wait on that stats is updated that will then potentially hold locks. This will then escalete badly when the table is hit with a large number of inserts at the same time as we have a large number of queries trying to fetch from the table. I may add that we are at least for now using READCOMITTED isolation level.

Comment: Thsnkd @Charlieface, that option had slipped my mind. Need to take a look if that will solve our issue.

Comment: But you said you "did turn on automatic update stats async" - so that solves the problem then? The problem you were trying to solve was queries waiting on stats to be synchronously generated and this option solves that so what other issue are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MartinSmith That is true but with the cost that all statistics updates are are asynchronous with the risk that some queries may degrade with stale statistics.

Comment: Guess it depends on your workload. That will only be an issue if you are doing some bulk update that totally invalidates the existing stats, for transactional workloads IME in most cases stats are just considered out of date because the threshold for modifications is reached gradually and so continuing with the old stats for slightly longer is not a big issue